# PHP How to get specific part of Amazon API JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I use the Amazon product advertising API to retrieve product information on my websit in a JSON array.

When calling the API, an example result I am getting is the following, which is shown when using `print_r($response)`.

```
{"ItemsResult":{"Items":[{"ASIN":"B010FTYIUS","DetailPageURL":"https://www.amazon.com/dp/B010FTYIUS?tag=hangarflights-20&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1","Offers":{"Listings":[{"Id":"DAjnW3%2BLO70EsyLN%2FMQLwyvR8afWckVN8fvJ6mojtJQMdPh0yCEgxtv3gBjPMOwUQp8RvEP56ao%2FWFAtjhHkFRQRsYs27pFtiLuL9DiaqdIprrqGBw03IQ%3D%3D","Price":{"Amount":1095.95,"Currency":"USD","DisplayAmount":"$1,095.95"},"ViolatesMAP":false}]}}]}}
```

How can I get, for example, just the price amount (here 1095.95)? I have tried multiple things such as `echo $response["ItemsResult"]["items"]["Offers"]["Listings"]["Price"]["Amount"]` but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$response = '{"ItemsResult":{"Items":[{"ASIN":"B010FTYIUS","DetailPageURL":"https://www.amazon.com/dp/B010FTYIUS?tag=hangarflights-20&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1","Offers":{"Listings":[{"Id":"DAjnW3%2BLO70EsyLN%2FMQLwyvR8afWckVN8fvJ6mojtJQMdPh0yCEgxtv3gBjPMOwUQp8RvEP56ao%2FWFAtjhHkFRQRsYs27pFtiLuL9DiaqdIprrqGBw03IQ%3D%3D","Price":{"Amount":1095.95,"Currency":"USD","DisplayAmount":"$1,095.95"},"ViolatesMAP":false}]}}]}}';
$response = json_decode($response, true);



echo $response["ItemsResult"]["Items"][0]['Offers']["Listings"][0]["Price"]["Amount"]; //1095.95
```

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly. I missed the [0]. Thanks a lot for the help!